# How to remove Branch Group in Java 3D?

Tags: java, java-3d

My code is
 public  BranchGroup create3dRoatating() {

```
      objRoot_child = new BranchGroup();
      objRoot_child.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_CHILDREN_EXTEND) ;
      objRoot_child.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_DETACH );
      objRoot_child.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_CHILDREN_WRITE) ;
      objRoot_child.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_CHILDREN_READ);
       tg_child = new TransformGroup();
       tg_child .setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
       tg_child.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_READ);
       tg_child .setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_CHILDREN_EXTEND);
      t3d_child = new Transform3D();

      t3d_child.setTranslation(new Vector3d(-0.62, 1.2, 0.0));
       t3d_child.setRotation(new AxisAngle4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
       tg_child.setTransform(t3d_child);

       tg_ship = new TransformGroup();

      tg_ship.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
      tg_ship.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_READ);
      tg_ship.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_CHILDREN_EXTEND);
      tg_ship.addChild(createObjLoad("model/Cargo Ship.obj"));

        alpha = new Alpha(-1,15000);

       axis = new Transform3D();
     //  axis.setRotation(new AxisAngle4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

       rotator = new RotationInterpolator(alpha, tg_ship, axis, 0.0f, (float) Math.PI * (2.0f));

      BoundingSphere bounds = new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 10000.0);

      rotator.setSchedulingBounds(bounds);

      tg_ship.addChild(rotator);
      tg_child.addChild(tg_ship);
      objRoot_child.addChild(tg_child);
      objRoot_child.addChild(createLight());

      objRoot_child.compile();

      return objRoot_child;

     }
```

public void load_sphere() {

```
      group = new BranchGroup();
      group.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_DETACH );
      group.setCapability( BranchGroup.ALLOW_CHILDREN_WRITE);
      group.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_CHILDREN_READ);

     Sphere sphere = new Sphere(0.2f);
    //  Cude3d  cube = new  Cude3d (0.2);
     //cube.setCapability(Shape3D.ALLOW_GEOMETRY_READ);
    // cube.setCapability(Geometry.ALLOW_INTERSECT);
    // group.addChild(cube);

     group.addChild(sphere);

     Color3f light1Color = new Color3f(1f, 1f, 1f);
     Vector3f light1Direction = new Vector3f(4.0f, -7.0f, -12.0f);
      BoundingSphere bounds =

                new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(0.0,0.0,0.0), 100.0);
     DirectionalLight light1

       = new DirectionalLight(light1Color, light1Direction);
```

light1.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);

```
    TransformGroup td_sphere=new TransformGroup();
    Transform3D tg_sphere=new Transform3D();
    td_sphere.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
    tg_sphere.setTranslation(new Vector3d(-0.62, 1.2, 0.0));
    td_sphere.setTransform(tg_sphere);
   // group.addChild(td_sphere);
    //group.addChild(light1);
    tg_child.addChild(group);
   // group.detach();

    }

     public void remove_sphere() {  

         //tg_child.removeChild(group);
         group.detach();
    //  group.setCollidable(true);
       // System.out.println(tg_child.getChild(0)); 
    }
```

After setting the capabilities of parent branch group( objRoot_child) and child branch group( group) i am getting this error
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czxBD.png) 
Any kind of help is appreciated.
Name of this file is Ship_3d.java.

Comment: Format your code, add a `java-3d` tag. And paste your stack trace as text.